# Problems when trying to mimic Scala option in Java

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to solve a Java problem, basically I would like to mimic the behaviour of Scala Option in Java by implementing a Option class. I was given several tests to make sure that my implementation works as expected. The first test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void Empty_Option_Has_No_Value() {
    Assert.assertFalse(Option.<SomeClass> createEmptyOption()
            .hasValue());
}
```

Have you ever seen the `"Option.<SomeClass> createEmptyOption()"` notation?? I have been trying to create a createEmptyOption() method that returns a Option instance but my code does not compile.

Any suggestions on how to implement the createEmptyOption() method??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is a generic method type argument. It can be used to infer the generic type of a method (or constructor) invocation.

Comment: @user2523463 What version of Java are you using to do this? What is the compilation error?

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys, I have managed to implement the class ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax used is to call a generic *method* with a type argument. Your method should look like this:

```
public abstract class Optional<T> {

    public static <O> Optional<O> createEmptyOption() {
        return new EmptyOptional<>();
    }
}
```

i.e. you have a generic method that returns an `Optional<O>`.

If you invoke it like so:

```
final Optional<Integer> optI = Optional.createEmptyOption();
```

Then the compiler will infer `O` to be `Integer`. If you invoke it without explicit assignment like you do the the compiler cannot infer the type so you need to provide it. This is what the syntax does.

Look at the source code for [Guava's `Optional`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Optional.java?r=806967c3660d231e62a52674703acb51ec4e6623) for implementation ideas.

Comment: Thank you Boris the Spider for your help!!I have just managed to finish my Option class and the tests are all green ;)